# Summing a column in VBA.

Tags: vba, excel

My VBA skills are weak, I appreciate any help anyone can offer. I appologize if this question is too basic...

I Have an excel doc that will have an unknown number of amounts that need to be summed, the sum needs to be in the last cell after the final amount. So far this is what I have,

```
Dim rRecoveryAmt As Long

    rRecoveryAmt = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("AN" & rRecoveryAmt) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("AN2:AN" & rRecoveryAmt - 1))
```

Not getting an error, but not getting any results either.  Am I missing something blatenly obvious?

Thanks

Comment: That code works for me. Perhaps it is not running in the correct worksheet?

Comment: When you get a result it populates in the cell below the last record for AN column? It appears to execute with no issues, but just not populating anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct to me.  If you're trying to put the actual formula in, you can use:

```
Dim rRecoveryAmt As Long

    rRecoveryAmt = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("A" & rRecoveryAmt).Formula = "=Sum(A2:A" & rRecoveryAmt - 1 & ")"
```

Otherwise, as Andy G stated, you can be sure it's on the right sheet by fully qualifying the objects:

```
Sheets("Sheetname").cells(...
```

Comment: I think I found it.

        Dim rRecoveryAmt As Long

            rRecoveryAmt = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row
            Range("AN" & rRecoveryAmt + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("AN2:AN" & rRecoveryAmt - 1))

Comment: I had to add + 1 to the Range("AN" & rRecoveryAmt) it was placing the formula in the last column. once I added the +1 it placed it 1 cell below the last record.